# mysql query failing in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run the following query in php, but its failing.

```
$results = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO book_loans
VALUES (:book_id, :branch_id, :card_no, CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY))");

//Binding params and executing insert for checking out
$results->bindParam(':book_id', $book_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$results->bindParam(':branch_id', $branch_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$results->bindParam(':card_no', $card_no, PDO::PARAM_STR);

if($results->execute()) {
    return array("success");
} else {
    return array("failure");
}
```

I am returning arrays with strings to check back and display a message.
But even for valid elements, the query is failing.

Comment: So why don't you check for what error does MySQL return?

Comment: query itself runs fine in mysql, problem's probably in the php code

Comment: But you can use MySQL functions to get that error back and debug accordingly

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: Do a SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; before insert to make sure is not a foreign key issue.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky

checked error-info:
its returning, 'Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) '

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message?

Usually the cause is an error in the SQL query! Check that the query actually works in the MySQL console.

If you require more specific help you need post the desription of the **book_loans** table. Can you post the create table statement for this table?

Comment: The query works fine when i run it on cmd!

Here's the create table command:
CREATE TABLE book_loans (
 book_id     varchar(15),
 branch_id   int(5),
 card_no     varchar(10),
 date_out    date,
 due_date    date,
 PRIMARY KEY (book_id, branch_id, card_no),
 FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES book(book_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (branch_id) REFERENCES library_branch(branch_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (card_no) REFERENCES borrower(card_no)
);

Comment: Can you try to add the values **date_out** and **due_date** explicitly instead of using MySQL functions? Maybe the php driver/framework cannot handle these.

Answer (score 0):

In stead of returning array ('failure') return array($results->errorInfo()), analyze the error text and then fix it